# Will resetting Windows 10 also reset drivers for touchpad and keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, acer-aspire, reset, synaptics-touchpad

If we reset the laptop, will it get back to the original touchpad and keyboard driver settings?

What happened is that, when I turned off the touchpad settings, the touchpad driver was automatically removed. I tried to reinstall the touchpad drivers, but it's not working. Now I want the original driver settings back.

My laptop is an AcerE5-575G.

Comment: I can't be sure, but I think it does preserve existing drivers. I did a complete clean install from USB, which ended up with a dozen missing drivers, then restored from an old backup and used the Win10 reset, which kept those drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Windows should automatically install the drivers required to operate the touchpad or keyboard. If it doesn't I would say there is a fault with your device.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: But how am I meant to gain reputation points if every answer that I give I'm being told it's not an answer. What about it isn't an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try downloading the driver from the manufacturers website and install it first (use a mouse)

Resetting windows would probably get back your touchpad working, but it is possible that features like multi-touch wouldn't work since it will install a generic driver. Anyway, after installing fresh Windows 10 (reset is similar to this), you are going to have to install the drivers for this. So it is better try it first. Resetting Windows is quite close to a clean install, so this would reset the drivers.